# Selenium or Eggplant

Tags: selenium, web-testing, ui-testing

we are just trying to evaluate which one is best - Selenium or Eggplant

Selenium is of course free of cost. The following are some problems we faced:
1. click actually requires focus on the page. so when a test case is running we just have to see the selenium running. Any click by the user, for example if i want the test case to run in background, then i can't do that. I dont know how fireEvent() method will help in this case.

1. Our application has many form and any click or value change or focus on any element reloads(through ajax) some component on the webpage. So the page is fully ajax driven. So we were getting many Stalereference exceptions when using selenium. We handled this with using our own wrappers on top of webelement which handles such exceptions.

Will eggplant be a better alternative?

Comment: I would prefer Eggplant if it is mobile application else selenium is the best choice to automate web pages...

Answer (score 0):

The Automation tools have to have the browser open to truly do the automation tests.  It's an actual representation of what the end-user would do (clicks, changing URL, clicking browser [BACK]/[FORWARD] buttons, key-presses, etc..), so it must launch an instance of the browser.  Selenium IDE can only run in Mozilla Firefox, but if you set up Selenium Remote Control server, and choose a client (NUnit using .NET, JUnit using Java, etc..) and launch your browser from Visual Studio (using NUnit) or from Eclipse (using JUnit), then you can test your script in multiple browsers.  They also have Web Driver which is a newer way architecture than Selenium RC (Remote Control).

I've never used Eggplant, so I can't criticize on it.

As for the things you had issues with during your proof of concept, I can help you with those.  Selenium is actually JavaScript running on top of any JavaScript running on your page (ie: AJAX in your case), so it will work fine for those situations.  Can you describe the behavior of the StaleReference Exceptions?

Comment: Note to those coming here later that this answer is relevant to Selenium 1, but Selenium 2 runs on a variety of browsers through their native hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Selenium and Webdriver. In ChromeDriver, the browser can actually run in background (verified by myself :) )

So I would suggest Selenium - and moreover, you can find support here ;)